# What do these characters on an antique mural painting translate to? (Top middle and upper right are duplicates; only appear once)

Tags: character-identification, traditional-characters, seal

[image: enter preformatted text here]

This is a screen shot of closeups of each character / seal appearing in the lower left of an antique Chinese mural. The top middle and upper right are duplicates, only appearing once. The order in which the characters appear is likely skewed. Your help better understanding this family heirloom spanning several generations would be so greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: The top middle/right is repeat of the last three in a signature I believe （＾ν＾）

Answer (score 0):

the middle row, right to left:

[貞](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk//Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%B2%9E)

[恭](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk//Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%81%AD)

[繪](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk//Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%B9%AA)

the bottom row, right to left:

maybe, not sure [集](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk//Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E9%9B%86)

[臣](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk//Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%87%A3)

[秉](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk//Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%A7%89)

top left:

唐？？印

the seal of mr 唐, given name is not yet recognised

Comment: The bottom right word looks like "焦".